# JQuery addClass and removeClass problems

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, addclass, removeclass

I have some code that when a user clicks on a link  JQuery adds class 'selected' to that anchor. Then, so that not all links end up with 'selected' as the user  clicks on different links, I tried using .removeClass to remove those classes from any elements before adding it to the one clicked.

However, I've run into issues where classes are being removed, but not being added. To make things even stranger.. it works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE9 and FF4 only one link is having a class added (first link, bio) to it (regardless of what order I click links)...And Safari 5.05 doesn't seem to work on any of them.

I tried pasting all of my code into JSFiddle, but I couldn't get it to work correctly in JSlint (I'll post it anyways)..

Here's my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').load('bio.html .content'); // fill #content when page loads
$('#heading a').click(function(){ 
    $('#content').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' .content' );
    $('#heading li a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false; 
});    });
```

Here's part of the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="heading" class="transparent">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>Test1</h1>
        <h3>Test2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="transparent">
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio" class="transparent">
        <p>Portfolio examples will go here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="transparent"><h2>Test3</h2></div>
</body>
```

And here's the JSFiddle, although I think I must have things posted wrong (Never used JSFiddle).. http://jsfiddle.net/PhHrX/3/

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help you can throw my way.

Edit:
Here's the complete CSS: http://pastebin.com/g8zLGR76
Here's the complete HTML: http://pastebin.com/CR1Y2595

Comment: Unless it's only not working in IE, working in one compliant browser but not in another is a red flag that something is not up to standards or code compliance.  Have you run your page through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) yet?

Comment: HTML validated perfectly as an XHTML 1.1 document in CSE HTMl Validator 9.0. CSS validated in there as well, other than a few things it didn't recognize; such as box-shadow and border-radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its your CSS change the selector .selected to....

```
#heading ul li a.selected {background: #FF0000;}
```

Comment: This worked as well. Although, I don't see why the way I had it wouldn't work... or why if I merely had ".selected {background-color: #FF0000;}" wouldn't work either. As long as there was a class named 'selected', I would think that it should have worked.

Comment: It's because you have these selectors #heading a:link, a:visited , 
#heading a:hover tags. I'm not exactly sure why, but those are considered more specific, and so those styles were over-writing yours.

Comment: Ah, yes.. I see. I should have known that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it actually has to do with your CSS. if you put an !important after the rule, it works dandily.

http://jsfiddle.net/PhHrX/10/

Comment: Is adding !important 'cheating' to make it work, or is it totally ok to add !important? I remember reading a blog a front-end guy posted about !important, and he made it seem that using it was just a way of being lazy (in most cases).  Adding !important to the CSS rule did make it work across Chrome, FF4, IE9, and Safari 5.05.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used the `.siblings()` selector to accomplish this.

```
$('#heading a').click(function () { 
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' .content' );
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: I think that would have worked well if I were applying the style to the <li> items themselves. However, since I'm applying it to the <a> elements inside the <li>, the <a> elements inside other <li> items wouldn't be considered siblings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it's because you haven't used `each()`, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').load('bio.html .content'); // fill #content when page loads
    $('#heading li').each(function() {
        $('a', this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' .content' );
            $('#heading li a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: True, I'm new to JQuery, and I didn't know about each(). However, after updating my JQuery to what you've posted I have the same result as before across the browsers.

Comment: Would doing it that way be considered a type of 'best practices'? Since it would still work the way I had it now that the CSS problem was fixed?

Comment: Yeah I would highly advise doing it this way. It is better practice yeah. So all this time it was a css problem? Maybe I should have taken a look at your jsfiddle before having posted lol.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').load('bio.html .content'); // fill #content when page loads
$('#heading a').click(function(){ 
    $('#content').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' .content' );
    $('#heading li a').removeClass('selected');
   setTimeout(function() { $(this).addClass('selected'); }, 200);
    return false; 
});    });
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is done so that there's a pause between the class being remove, and the class being added... to make sure that the class isn't added then removed by the function? So even though the function is ordered in the way I'd want things to happen that doesn't mean that it'll actually happen that way?